# SOLR Snowball Porter for Arabic

Tags: solr, solr4, porter-stemmer, snowball

is there a Snowball Porter Filter or any similar filter for Arabic?

`<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />`

I need it to normalize plural words into singular words for the Arabic language

Answer (score 0):

Solr does provide language support for quite a wide range of [languages](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis).
Check for the Arabic ones @ [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Arabic)

Documentation :-

```
Provides character normalization and stemming
```

If you have english and arabic text you can check [Solr Language Detection](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection) which will help you keep the fields separate and search accordingly.

Comment: I've included those 2 filters, but they do not do the work of the Snowball Porter Filter Factory
Searching for an English word wouldn't match an index containing the corresponding singular word